# UIView custom class isnt showed in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, xib, subview

I have an TutorialInitialView .xib, .m, .h UIView extended class, then I have a `UIViewController` and in the `viewDidLoad` I do the following:

```
TutorialInitialView *vti=[[TutorialInitialView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
[self.MBMeterContainer addSubview:vti];
```

But when I run in the simulator the TutorialInitialView doesn´t appear.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the xib, not alloc init the class.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:"TutorialInitialView" bundle: nil];
TutorialInitialView *vti= [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];
[self.MBMeterContainer addSubview:vti];
```